# Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$. Is $\{1, 2\}$ an element of $A$, a subset of $A$, both or neither?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$.

(a) Is $\{1, 2\}$ an element of $A$, a subset of $A$, both or neither?

(b) Is $\{2, 3\}$ an element of $A$, a subset of $A$, both or neither?

(c) Is $1$ an element of $A$, a subset of $A$, both or neither?

Solution:

(a)

Let $B = \{1,2\}$

B is an element of A because it's in A. $\{1,2\}$ is not a subset of A because not every element of A is in B.

(b) Let $C = \{2,3\}$. $\{2,3\}$, and its not an element of A because it's not in A. It's also not a subset of A because not every element of A is in C.

(c) $1$ is an element of A but not a subset for same reason as (a)

Comment: You read the definition of a subset upside down. $B$ is a subset of $A$ if every element of $B$ (!!!) is in $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $B$ to be a subset of $A$ you need every element of $B$ to be an element of $A$, not vice versa. Both $1$ and $2$ are elements of $A$, so actually $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of $A$.